# unable to send status message to twitter using python3.3 and its package twitter-1.9.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

Using the twitter-1.9.0 (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter/1.9.0)
I am trying to send a status message but unable to do it. below is the code snippet.

```
import twitter as t

# consumer and authentication key values are provided here.

def tweet(status):
    if len(status) > 140 :
        raise Exception ('Status message too long !!!')
    authkey = t.Twitter(auth=t.OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))
    authkey.statuses.update(status)

....

price = 99.99
status = "buy price is $" + str(price)
tweet(status)
```

error is coming like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tanmaya/Documents/prog/py_prog/progs/getprice.py", line 42, in <module>
    tweet(status)
  File "/home/tanmaya/Documents/prog/py_prog/progs/getprice.py", line 17, in tweet
    authkey.statuses.update(status)
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Line number may be different. I am slightly new to these web modules and programs of python. please help !!

**please note** : i am using python 3.3 so I got this one only (twitter-1.9.0), from the python3.3 package pages. my complete program is a bit longer, so i donot want to move to other version of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the sample usage of the package you posted, you should be using the following syntax inside your `def tweet(status):`

```
authkey.statuses.update(status=status)
```

Note the use of the `status=status`... to use a keyword argument, rather than a positional parameter

**To clarify, your code becomes**

```
def tweet(status):
    if len(status) > 140 :
        raise Exception ('Status message too long !!!')
    authkey = t.Twitter(auth=t.OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))
    authkey.statuses.update(status=status) # <----- only this line changes

....

price = 99.99
status = "buy price is $" + str(price)
tweet(status)
```

Comment: after doing that i got the below error\n     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/tanmaya/Documents/prog/py_prog/progs/getprice.py", line 41, in <module>
        tweet(status=status1)
    TypeError: tweet() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'

Comment: Err - have you changed your `tweet` function `def tweet(status=status)`? Don't do that - change the line I pointed out **inside** your `tweet` function

Comment: No I have changed at the position you told.\n                                                                  def tweet(status1):\n
    \tif len(status) > 140 :\n
        \traise Exception ('Status message too long !!!')\n
    authkey = t.Twitter(auth=t.OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))\n
    authkey.statuses.update(status=status1)\n
\n
price = 99.99\n
status1 = "buy price is $" + str(price)\n
tweet(status=status1)

Comment: @tanmay updated post to make it more explicit on what needs changing - your `tweet` function definition and call don't need changing

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help at 1:50 AM (night here :-) )

Comment: just for knowledge sake would you explain me why that was happening (I am not able to understand, why we need to write that exact things "status keyword" , but in some other python defined functions, we donot have to ?!!

Comment: It's the way the library you're using has been written to work (because of the way it chooses to work with twitter) - if you look at the most of the commands it provides, they're mostly keyword arguments because it uses attribute access to mimic the URL structure of twitter requests and your keyword arguments become parameters to the URL. Python isn't like that in general - I would just bear it in mind using this library though :)

Comment: thanks, a lot. even in the site of the python3.3 module twitter 1.9.0, the last program is error prone (this error !!).